# Caching Images in Angular

Tags: angular, caching

I am having around 300 designs and I am loading all at a time. I would like to cache those images instead of calling server everytime. (My desings won't change most of the time). Below is the code, of how I am loading them. What would be the best approach to cache them.

app-thumbnail is a different component where I am only loading image.

```
 <div *ngFor="let design of designs">
      <div (click)="showDesignDetails(design.designId)">
          <app-thumbnail [designId]="design.designId"></app-thumbnail>          
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Realistically, the browser should already be caching the image. Assuming that your reason for wanting to cache is your browser being slow, it's probably not caused by a lack of caching, but because of _rendering_ the images. Have you considered lazy loading the images to solve your issue.

Comment: Are you talking about loading 50 and then 50 and so on ?Not sure how lazy loading works with my scenario. Any articles?

Comment: 50 is a bit much, but generally, only load images either right before they appear, or once they appear on the page.

Comment: also, regarding your scenario. If your issue is that you feel the browser loads slowly, then caching is probably *not* going to help. The reason the browser is being slow is because it's trying to *render* 300 images, which blocks a lot of stuff from running. The question you're asking has an incorrect assumption that the browser isn't caching your images. You can increase the cache time (IE: extend how long the browser caches the images), but you should make sure to lazy load your images to help performance.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways:

1) [Application Cache Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). According to the documentation,

> Developers can use the Application Cache (AppCache) interface to
>   specify resources that the browser should cache and make available to
>   offline users. Applications that are cached load and work correctly
>   even if users click the refresh button when they are offline.

2) [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). Through the use of service workers, you can cache various types of resources, including images and network requests.

Though this brings me to the topic of using [Progressive Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) (PWA). Since you are using Angular, you can easily set it up as a PWA (which is based on the usage of service workers) by following the official Angular [guide](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) for setting up service workers.

Comment: I found your option 1 here in stackoverflow, Not sure I can go that because of people using different browsers(even IE). will try that. Second one is interesting, have to do my research. Thanks

Comment: @Chatra these days, people are adopting service workers as that's where the trend is heading to

Comment: Quick note: don't bother with application caches anymore. Moving away from them isn't so much a trend as it is a necessity. They're being deprecated, so just use service workers instead.

Comment: application cache manifest link is dead

Answer (score -1):

This is not the correct way to cache the image, but
we can use this technique.

we can put this snippet in the application,

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;position:absolute;">
  <img src="example.com" />
</div>
```

So, image will be cached & browser can load it wherever it is needed.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can use [ng-lazyload-image](https://github.com/tjoskar/ng-lazyload-image)

> A small libary for lazy loading images for Angular apps with zero dependencies

```
npm install ng-lazyload-image

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'image',
  template: `
    <img [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image">
  `
})
class ImageComponent {
  defaultImage = 'https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000';
  image = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0?fm=jpg';
}
```